# Regular expression - extract numeric n character

Tags: regex

how to extract numeric n character from 1960102214217F by using regular expression ??

I tried somthing like this `([0-9*])\+([A-Z*])` but result return Match failed!!

Comment: Does `n` stand for `and` in your language?

Comment: The expression you used, while not quite correct, should match the string you gave as an example. Can you provide your full code?

Comment: which RegExp implementation would be the target? From the example you've given I guess .NET is OK?

Answer (score 3):

You can find it with following perl code:

```
$v = "1960102214217F";
$v =~ s/^(\d+)\D*$/$1/;
```

This means that regular expression `/^(\d+)\D*$/` would find a number for you. Here `^` and  `$` are beginning and end of the string correspondingly. `\d` stands for numbers, `\D` stands for everything which is not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
([0-9]+)([A-Z])
```

That `*` will mess up numeric matching.

Answer (score 0):

try this one for .NET:

```
([0-9]+)
```

you might find this software handy if you're doing .NET: [RegExp Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/)

Answer (score 0):

The * needs to be outside of the brackets, not inside.

So try

```
([0-9]*)+([A-Z]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]+[A-Z]*
```

will match that. It simply means one or more numeric characters with zero or more upper-case letters following it. Is that what you wanted?
If you just want to get the single letter (only one), you can use:

```
(?<=\d+)([A-Z]{1})$
```

- (?<=\d+) is a look-behind for one or more numbers
- ([A-Z]*) is the matching group and will match zero or more upper-case letters following one or more numbers
- $ is the end of the string

Look-behinds will not be included in the match.

Comment: Your second pattern will match after each digit. `123A` -> 3 matches. (even without the `A` at the end...)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I fixed it. Plus I added an example how to get at the number when there is only 1.